# UIGestureRecognizers for view in a scroll view

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm using a few `UIGestureRecognizer`s to pan, rotate and scale a view, which resides inside a scroll view.

My problem is that sometimes the scroll view eats the touches *before* the gesture recognizers do, so when this happens I end up zooming the scroll view instead of dragging the view. (It doesn't happen all the time. I still can't describe how to reproduce this behavior).

I'm pretty sure this can be solved in some way. For example `MPMoviePlayerController` doesn't have this problem: in fact, you can put it in a scroll view, and when you pinch it, it works just fine (i.e. it doesn't zoom the outer scroll view too). Does anyone know how does `MPMoviePlayerController` achieve this?

I've already searched for answers on SO, with no results. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: This is just an idea, I haven't tested this.

`UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` defines `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`. You could try implementing this on your gesture recognizer delegate. This won't prevent the  scroll view from zooming. To prevent zooming you could try temporary setting `maximumZoomScale` `minimumZoomScale` to `zoomScale` in the recognizer action method.

Comment: It's a bit of an hack, but this seems to be working, thanks. I'll leave the question open in case someone else has a better solution, otherwise I'll accept this one and you'll get the bounty.

Comment: Excellent solution!  I wouldn't say it was hack, it may well be what it is intended for.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess your rotation is conflicting with zoom - both probably require two touches?

In which case try creating a one touch rotation.

Or disable zooming on the scrollview and implement zooming/scaling via pinch gesture recognizer.

see:

http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/14/working-with-uigesturerecognizers/

Comment: I thought scrollviews already use gesture recognizers? They reimplemented it using them since 3.2. If so, isn't there a way to tell the scrollview's recognizer that it should fail if I'm trying to pinch my view? I already tried using `requireGestureRecognizerToFail` on all scrollview's recognizers, but I can't zoom the scrollview if I do it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not set `scrollEnabled(NO)` on your UIScrollView?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html

> If the value of this property is YES , scrolling is enabled, and if it
>   is NO , scrolling is disabled. The default is YES.
>
> When scrolling is disabled, the scroll view does not accept touch
>   events; it forwards them up the responder chain.

Things like `zoomToRect:animated:` don't say anything about being disabled by this flag; I'd assume that would keep working when you pan/zoom/scroll in response to your gesture events.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can differentiate zoom in/zoom out and scrolling functionality by identify number of tap option on UIScrolView. Here i do same things as you want. you may try it.

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

imgview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"]];
view1=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 400)];
view1.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
[view1 addSubview:imgview];


objscrollview.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
objscrollview.contentSize=CGSizeMake(300, 400);
objscrollview.minimumZoomScale=1;
objscrollview.maximumZoomScale=10;
[objscrollview addSubview:view1];

UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap)];
singleFingerTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[objscrollview addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
[singleFingerTap release];
}

//Single tap on scrollview call below method
-(void)handleSingleTap
{
    NSLog(@"Singletap identify");
}


//While perform zoom  in/zoom out action on scroll view it's delegate method call
//In this method, we are return view that want to zoom in/Zoom out..


 - (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView1
{
    NSLog(@"hi++++++++++++++++++");
    return imgview;
}
```